# Reordering all rows of a datatable based on one of the fields

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

**I have a DataTable with columns such as the following:**

```
Field1 | val 1 | val 2 | val 3
Field2 | val 1 | val 2 | val 3
Field3 | val 1 | val 2 | val 3
Field4 | val 1 | val 2 | val 3
```

and so so on.. all the way to Field20

What would be the best way to completely reorder the rows before binding to the grid on my page. I would use the Field column to determine where each row should go.

I did research and saw that one of the only techniques was to Clone, Delete, Re-insert the row where it should go.

If I have to do this for all of the rows since none of the rows are in their correct position does anyone have a good way of doing it?

Here is what I tried:

```
    DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
    DataRow[] row = dataTable1.Select("Field ='" + "Field2" +"'");
    dataTable2 .Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```

Comment: That sounds like a plan, is there anyway you can look at my updated example and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to sort your DataTable. The result of the LINQ operation (dt2) is IEnumerable, but you can still it to bind your grid.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add("Key1Value", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("Key2Value", 3);
dt.Rows.Add("Key3Value", 4);
dt.Rows.Add("Key4Value", 5);
dt.Rows.Add("Key5Value", 0);
dt.Rows.Add("Key6Value", 1);

var dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("Position"));
foreach (DataRow dr in dt2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dr["Key"], dr["Position"]);
}
```

I edited my code so it matches your sort order. I add a column named Position, so I can sort it anyway I want. Just change the value of Position if you want different order.

If you don't want to add an extra column, you can use switch statement in the OrderBy method.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("Key1Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Key2Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Key3Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Key4Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Key5Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Key6Value");

var dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x =>
    {
        switch (x.Field<string>("Key"))
        {
            case "Key5Value": return 0;
            case "Key6Value": return 1;
            case "Key1Value": return 2;
            case "Key2Value": return 3;
            case "Key3Value": return 4;
            case "Key4Value": return 5;
            default : return -1;
        }
    }
);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr["Key"]);
}
```

Basically, the OrderBy() method accepts an anonymous method that define the sort order. Since "Key5Value" returns 0, then it is placed before "Key6Value" (returns 1). Use OrderByDescending() method if you want to sort it from largest value to smallest value.

I also edit your code. The getPosition method is similar to what the OrderBy() method in my LINQ code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("Key1Value");
        dt.Rows.Add("Key2Value");
        dt.Rows.Add("Key3Value");
        dt.Rows.Add("Key4Value");
        dt.Rows.Add("Key5Value");
        dt.Rows.Add("Key6Value");

        var dt2 = dt.Clone();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string key = dr["Key"].ToString();
            var dRow = dt2.NewRow();
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dt2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, getPosition(key));
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr["Key"]);
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static int getPosition(string key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case "Key5Value":
                return 0;
            case "Key6Value":
                return 1;
            case "Key1Value":
                return 2;
            case "Key2Value":
                return 3;
            case "Key3Value":
                return 4;
            case "Key4Value":
                return 5;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Version 2:
I add a dictionary which contains the key value (eg. Key1Value) and a pair of values. The pair values are the new key value (eg. Key 1 Value) and the position. The reason I use a dictionary is to replace the switch-case expression. You can add additional value if you want. Just add more type to the tuple.

```
Tuple<string, int, int, bool> // holds a sequence of a string, two integers and a boolean.
```

Here's the complete code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // create table
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Val1", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Val2", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Val3", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(int));

        // populate table
        dt.Rows.Add("Key1Value", 100, 200, 300);
        dt.Rows.Add("Key2Value", 100, 200, 300);
        dt.Rows.Add("Key3Value", 100, 200, 300);
        dt.Rows.Add("Key4Value", 100, 200, 300);
        dt.Rows.Add("Key5Value", 100, 200, 300);
        dt.Rows.Add("Key6Value", 100, 200, 300);

        // initialize dictionary
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, int>>() {
            { "Key1Value", new Tuple<string, int>("Key 1 Value", 2) }, // Key1Value's new value is Key 1 Value, position is 2
            { "Key2Value", new Tuple<string, int>("Key 2 Value", 3) },
            { "Key3Value", new Tuple<string, int>("Key 3 Value", 4) },
            { "Key4Value", new Tuple<string, int>("Key 4 Value", 5) },
            { "Key5Value", new Tuple<string, int>("Key 5 Value", 0) },
            { "Key6Value", new Tuple<string, int>("Key 6 Value", 1) }
        };

        // set position and new key value
        dt.AsEnumerable()
          .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => {
                        x["Position"] = dict[x.Field<string>("Key")].Item2;
                        x["Key"] = dict[x.Field<string>("Key")].Item1; // must be the last because the dictionary key is "KeyXValue", not "Key X Value"
                     });

        // sort by Position
        var dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("Position"));

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", dr["Key"], dr["Val1"], dr["Val2"], dr["Val3"], dr["Position"]);
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution, but I don't know if I fully understand it. Will it give me full flexibility to place any of the 20 rows wherever I want? I don't really have a field that I can sort by. I need to say if Key="Field2" insert at index 0, if Key="Field4" insert at index 1, and so on..

Comment: I implemented your first solution since it made sense to me now, but will I be able to additionally change the name of the key before returning the order? For example all of my keys are database field names and I would like to add spaces in between the words. For example I need to change the actual value of Key from Key5Value to "Key 5 Value", It seems like I will only be able to do something like this using the second technique based off of mine that you provided

Comment: I tried implementing version 2 and it says 'The column key does not belong to table'. On this part: x["Position"] = dict[x.Field<string>("Key")].Item2; By the way my actual Key column is called CategoryName. I replaced everywhere you had Key with that and still getting the error.

Comment: ahh I figured out my problem. My source datatable has rows in it that I do not wish to add to the grid so I wasn't adding them to the dictionary. Therefore, I was getting an error saying key not valid in dictionary. I guess I can't really use this method unless I am using all of the rows in the datatable. Is there a way I can do a check to see if x.Field exists before using it. Basically, lets say Key6Value is in your datatable, but you don't want it in the end result. How would you avoid this.

Comment: I only use 2 values in the dictionary because I only want to replace 2 columns in the table (Key and Position). Column Val1, Val2 and Val3 are not included in the dictionary because I don't replace the values.

Comment: If you encounter an error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary", it means the key you are seeking is not found in the dictionary. See my remark when I replace the Position and Key in the ForEach() method. If I replace the Key column first, the same error will occur because the Key value in the DataTable is changed to "Key 1 Value", and it can't find that key in the dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84336/discussion-between-matthew-peterson-and-handoko-chen).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution that I could some up with due to time being a factor. Please comment if you feel like it can be done in a better way.

This technique involves creating a clone of the source datatable. Then looping through the source datatable and re-adding rows to datatable2 in the desired order.

```
// Make a clone of the source datatable
DataTable dataTable2 = dataTable1.Clone();
// Loop through each row in the source datatable and check for key
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable1.Rows)
{
    string key = dr["Key"].ToString();
    DataRow dRow = dataTable2.NewRow();
    switch (key)
    {
        case "Key5Value":
            // Rename actual key value if needed
            dr["Key"] = "Key Rename if needed";
            // Set new datarow item array to current row in loop item array
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            // Add datarow to desired position in dataTable 2
            dataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 0);
            break;
        case "Key6Value":
            dr["Key"] = "Key Rename if needed";
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 1);
            break;
        case "Key1Value":
            dr["Key"] = "Key Rename if needed";
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 2);
            break;
        case "Key2Value":
            dr["Key"] = "Key Rename if needed";
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 3);
            break;
        case "Key4Value":
            dr["Key"] = "Key Rename if needed";
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 4);
            break;
        case "Key3Value":
            dr["Key"] = "Key Rename if needed";
            dRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 5);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I modify your code to remove some duplicate rows. See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

1. Add a new column "IntegerKey" in the data table.
2. Update value of column "Integer Key" based on the desired column's value 
   e.g. when desired Column value is say "column2" then column "IntegerKey" value = 1
   when desired Column value is say "column1" then column "IntegerKey" value = 2
   when desired Column value is say "column4" then column "IntegerKey" value = 3
3. `datarows[] arrROWS = Datatable.Select(string.empty, "IntegerKey desc")`